# How to keep two database environment tables in sync by creating scripts using procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have one table in the DEV environment and the same table was in SIT environment too. But I have added a few columns in the DEV environment table that I need to sync in SIT environment also. So, I am wondering if this can be done using the stored procedure by creating scripts where first I will have to find the levels of the tables based on the parent-child relationship that I will deploy directly into the SIT environment using any deployment tool like GIT/ JENKINS and that will make the tables in sync.

---DEV Environment---

```
CREATE TABLE table_dev1 (
    e_id    NUMBER(10),
    e_name  VARCHAR2(10),
    e_location varchar2(10),
    constraint pk_table_dev primary key(e_id)
);


CREATE TABLE table_dev2 (
    e_id2    NUMBER(10),
    e_id NUMBER(10),
    e_name  VARCHAR2(10),
    e_location varchar2(10),
    constraint pk_table_dev primary key(e_id),
    constraint fk_table_dev2 foreign key(e_id) references table_dev1(e_id)
);
```

table_dev1 is the parent and table_dev2 is the child table so in this order only it should create
tables into the higher environment

---SIT Environment---

```
CREATE TABLE table_dev1 (
  e_id  NUMBER(10),
  e_name VARCHAR2(10),
  constraint pk_table_dev primary key(e_id)
);
```

The table which is already present in SIT has e_location column missing that needs to be synced
from DEV environment and also new table got created in DEV environment i.e table_dev2
that needs to create into the SIT environment or I can say in the script it should like

--check if the table exists or not

--If exist then check if all columns are present or not if not then sync

--If the table doesn't exist then create one.

Comment: Everything *inside* the database can be done via stored procedure. And everything *external* can be done at least with calls to OS commands (where you can put the script you need) from stored procedure. But the real issue is an effort to support this homegrown solution. According to the question guide: do you have any issues with your code or you do not know where to start from? For the former: please, describe which piece of code causes the issue. For the latter: please, describe what have you found about the location of table's metadata (columns) and connectivity between two databases.

Comment: @astentx Thanks for a quick turnaround. Actually, I am not sure where to start from.

Comment: Hi Team. This question was all about syncing of two tables from two environments and I am not what was unclear in this. Can someone let me know what they didn't understand because I got down voted for this question though I had explained everything. Also, provided examples etc.

Comment: Also facing this issue. I know some api frameworks has functionallity that updates the DBs. I think they use a script. That's how I'm going to try and solve it. I am going to compile a JSON object with the config of every table and use that in a script to update DBs

Comment: @MarkusAfricanus Thanks for responding. It would be helpful if you can share some more details on how you are proceeding with sample code